# how to add frame/border around new figure element in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

How to add a border or frame around both the figure including its caption?

I tried to use style for figure, but no border shows up. I do not want border around img, but around both figure and caption if any.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">    
<body>

     <figure style="border-width:thin">
       <img src="image.png">
       <figcaption>my image</figcaption>
     </figure>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a class and style them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reason, the predefined value of the `border-width` is not working. See the CSS code below:

```
figure {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Or you can do this:

```
<figure style="border: 1px solid #000">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x180.png">
    <figcaption>my image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Whichever is easier, take your pick.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/gNFpv/4/

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <style>
      .frame{
       border: 1px solid #000; /*outside border*/
       padding: 10px; /* creates whitespace between border & content */
    </style>
<body>

 <figure class="frame">
   <img src="image.png">
   <figcaption>my image</figcaption>
 </figure>

</body>
</html>
```